# Custom Calender with events Crashing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, ios10

I am using calendar with events it's working fine in iOS 9 when run same application iOS 10 its crash the app.

https://github.com/mmick66/CalendarView 
I can take calendar code from Github.

```
func createCalendar()->Void{
    let eventStore = EKEventStore();        
    let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)        
    newCalendar.title = "RK Events"

    let sourcesInEventStore = eventStore.sources        

    switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {            
        case .authorized:        
            accessCalender = true
        case .denied:
            accessCalender = false    
            return    
        case .notDetermined:
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted: Bool, NSError) -> Void in
                if granted {        
                    self.accessCalender = true    
                }else{          
                    self.accessCalender = false
                }
            })
        default: break
    }

    if accessCalender {
        newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{ (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
            source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue
        }.first!
        do {
            try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
            calendarIdentifier = newCalendar.calendarIdentifier    
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newCalendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "RKEVENTS")
        } catch {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Calendar could not save", message: (error as NSError).localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(OKAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        createCalendar()
    }
}

func initializeCalendar(){
    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let calIdentifier:String = prefs.value(forKey: "RKEVENTS") as? String {
        calendarIdentifier = calIdentifier

        if store.calendar(withIdentifier: calendarIdentifier) != nil {
            rkCalendar = store.calendar(withIdentifier: calendarIdentifier)
        } else {
            calendarIdentifier = ""
            createCalendar()
        }
        accessCalender = true
    } else {
        createCalendar()
    }   
}

func startDate() -> Date? {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.month = -1
    let today = Date()

    let threeMonthsAgo = (self.calendarView.calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: today, options: NSCalendar.Options())
    return threeMonthsAgo
}

func endDate() -> Date? {            
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()            
    dateComponents.year = 2;
    let today = Date()

    let twoYearsFromNow = (self.calendarView.calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: today, options: NSCalendar.Options())

    return twoYearsFromNow            
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {            
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let width = self.view.frame.size.width - 16.0 * 2
    let height = width + 40.0
    self.calendarView.frame = CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 80.0, width: width, height: height)
}        

// MARK : KDCalendarDelegate        
func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didSelectDate date : Date, withEvents events: [EKEvent]) {
    if events.count > 0 {
        let event : EKEvent = events[0]
        eventLabel.text = event.title
    } else {
        eventLabel.text = "No Events"
    }
}

func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didScrollToMonth date : Date) {            
    // self.datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
}

func saveEvents(startDate:Date,endDate:Date,title:String,notes:String)->Void{            
    let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: self.store)        
    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.notes = notes
    event.calendar = self.rkCalendar
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    let dateComponent = NSDateComponents()        
    dateComponent.day = 1
    let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponent as DateComponents, to: startDate)

    let predicate = self.store.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: newDate!, calendars: [self.rkCalendar])

    let existingEvents = self.store.events(matching: predicate)

    if (existingEvents.count == 0) {            
        do {
            try self.store.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch _ as NSError {
            return
        }        
    } else {            
        for singleEvent in existingEvents {            
            if singleEvent.title == title && singleEvent.startDate == startDate {            
            } else {            
                do {
                    try self.store.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                } catch _ as NSError {            
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func loadEventsInCalendar() {            
    if let  startDate = self.startDate(), let endDate = self.endDate() {
        let fetchEvents = { () -> Void in
            let predicate = self.store.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end:endDate, calendars: [self.rkCalendar])        
                if let eventsBetweenDates = self.store.events(matching: predicate) as [EKEvent]? {        
                    self.calendarView.events = eventsBetweenDates    
                }    
            }       
            if EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized {        
                store.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event, completion: {(granted, error ) -> Void in
                    if granted {
                        fetchEvents()
                    }
                })    
            }
            else {
                fetchEvents()
            }    
        }    
    }
```

when I can debug this code

Error in this lines

```
 **newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
                (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
                source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue

                }.first!**
```

its showing nil in the first.
After it's crashing, please help me.

Comment: It seems that there in no element in the resulting array of the filter, hence force unwrapping a `nil` value causes a runtime exception. Without more code, no one can tell why might the filter value be `nil`. You should go through the code running the debugger and see why is there no value in the filtered results.

Comment: @DávidPásztor  I can run the code in debugger it show the error in line first! how can over come this problem

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value after this line newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
                (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
                source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue

                }.first!

Comment: Set up a breakpoint before that line is reached and check the values of your variables to see why is that filter giving a `nil` result.

Comment: I can print the value after break point  po sourcesInEventStore.first it's showing error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'sourcesInEventStore'

Comment: when I can run this code in ios9 its working fine why not in iOS10

Comment: Don't print the value that you know is going to be `nil`... Try to look for the cause of the issue. Check the values in `sourcesInEventStore` for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152555/discussion-between-naga-and-david-pasztor).